# What is proper power / driver size to use with an Osram Oslon Black Flat Led board?

Tags: led, driver

I am trying to determine the proper power to send to my specialized LED board. The board consists of 6 Osram Oslon Black Flat Leds. I currently have 4 of these boards, 2 in each headlight. I have each headlight currently powered by a 12v 5amp buck boost regulated DC to DC power supply. I do not want to be sending too much current or power. This is a headlight LED board and thus will be used intermitted.

Here are some specs to the Osram Oslon Black Flat LEd:
Type: single die (lateral)
Binning: 8M7N (250 - 355 lm min.)
Rated voltage: typ. 3.05 V (min. 2.75 V, max. 3.75 V)
Forward current: 50 to 1,500 mA
Surge current (10 µs): 2,500 mA
Viewing angle: typ. 120° (at 50 % Iv)

And the data sheet can be found [here](https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-2493315/LUW%20HWQP.pdf)

And here is an image of the board:
[image]

Comment: This is a "specialized LED board" you designed, or (as the picture would imply) one made for a Dodge automobile? In either case, the appropriate supply to the board depends a great deal on whether the board expects "12 VDC Automotive power" (i.e. 13.5-15 VDC most of the time) and does the LED driving on-board, or whether you need to supply current-limited power to the board.

Comment: I am unsure as this information is not public, thus why I am here. They appear to work properly with the power I have given them, but I am trying to maintain led longevity. And yes this a Dodge specialized board.

Comment: To sum: I have 2 pairs of these boards. Each pair is currently sharing a 12V 5a DC to DC auto buck boost power supply. I am not creator of the boards I am the creator of custom headlights which use these boards. These boards are a Dodge 2020 new item and I can find no info on them. They appear to function with or without a regulated power supply so long as its a min of 10.4v.

Comment: This board was designed for compatibility  to a wide range of car voltages from 11 to 14.5V  and thus ideally a 12V battery is used with a current regulator. You can choose whatever power you need and expect a temperature rise according to the heatsink you add on. Start with your requirements for power , ah capacity and time used. YOu can have a dim light and momentary bright switch. But you need to define it. It also could use a lens to focus the beam.

Comment: Thank you. There is indeed already one input pin defined for "low" beams and one input for "high" beams. They use a shared ground pin. What I am most worried about is overpowering them. Is there a way to which this board could be overpowered? Thanks again.

Comment: Don't power the "low" and "high" beam inputs at the same time. They will probably tolerate it momentarily (as they do in automotive use so that there isn't a blackout between low and high)  but use one or the other, not both in terms of limiting power dissipation. Other than that, you may have limited control options as it's probably self-regulating, but you might gain some insight from observing current/.vs. voltage at voltages it will operate at (i.e. does it draw more current at lower voltage, or the same, or less - so is its regulation constant power, or not).

Comment: Great! Thank you all for your input!